# Binomial expression involving union and intersection of sets?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{V}$ be disjoint sets containing $m$ and $n$ elements, respectively, and let $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{U} \cup \mathcal{V}$. Show that the number of subsets $\mathcal{A}$ of $\mathcal{F}$ that contain $k$ elements and that also have the property that $\mathcal{A} \cap \mathcal{U}$ contains $i$ elements is $$\binom{m}{i} \binom{n}{k-1}.$$ Interpret this identity combinatorially.

Bit confused as to how to proceed... How can I interpret these binomial expressions?

Comment: There is a typo here. You must have meant
$\binom{m}{i}\binom{n}{k-i}$

Answer (score 1):

$\mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{U}$ contains $i$ elements. Hence to form such a set $\mathcal{A}$ you need to choose $i$ elements from the $m$ elements in $\mathcal{U}$, and the rest $k-i$ elements of $\mathcal{A}$ has to be chosen from the $n$ elements of $\mathcal{V}$. Hence the total number of such sets is
$$\binom{m}{i}\binom{n}{k-i}$$